# Is the MAC adress visible for non-internal network users like a websites?

Tags: networking, ip, mac

I was wondering if someone who isn't in the same network could see other's mac aadress, like websites, app's etc. Looked for it in topics but couldn't find a definitive answer for this question.

Comment: No.............

Comment: @joeqwerty: Not universally true with IPv6, unfortunately.

Comment: NB: The client seeing the MAC of a web server would usually be more or less irrelevant. On the other hand, the server seeing the MAC of the client ca be a massive privacy problem.

Comment: @Sven: I think the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAC Address are only exchange between hosts on the same network segment. They are used to add the source and destination addresses to a Frame. So in short a client on the internet will not see the MAC address of the server hosing the website.

In contrast the IP information is used to add the Source and Destination addresses to the IP Packet, these addresses stay with the packet and remain unchanged as the IP Packets travels between different networks. Of course if we are using NAT this also changes things.

Comment: "So in short a client on the internet will not see the MAC address of the server hosting the website."

The client can't see the mac's host, so the host can't see mac's client too, right?

Comment: @PhilippeLopes: True for IPv4.

Comment: @Sven: Today IPv6 is very used, so MAC adress could be used in future as IP to identify someone or a machine?

Comment: Possibly, Using the MAC as part of an IPv6 address is only one way IPv6 can be configured. you don't have to include the MAC as part of the IPv6 address although it will be / is a common way to configure IPv6. with IPv4 the MAC address is only used for the layer 2 frame so wont be visible beyond the network segment the host is on.

Comment: Thanks mates, I was with this doubt in my mind a long time and couldn't find a answer that makes me really understand how it works.

Comment: Not a problem Philippe, if you like the answer can you mark it as accepted.

Comment: Ok. I'm new here and I'm findind out how it works. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Not in IPv4, as the MAC is only contained in the headers of the ethernet frame that gets discarded when the router forwards it elsewhere.

For IPv6, the MAC address can be part of the IPv6 address (see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Stateless_address_autoconfiguration)